# How to fix VS Code Intellisense not recognizing Blazor Webassembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, blazor, intellisense

VSCode doesn't recognize Blazor components and throws "Found Markup element with unexpected name ''" warnings as well as not recognizing simple types such as IEnumerable. The project builds and compiles with no issues.

I tried making a fresh blazor webassembly project and the issues persist. I also tried reinstalling VSCode, the SDKs and runtimes, and ensuring that all using statements and package definitions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the version 2 of C# extension, just downgrade it to v1.26.0.

I had the same issue after update too. https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/4580

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to take advantage of the great Language Server features, you can revert back to using OmniSharp by going to the Extension settings and setting dotnet.server.useOmnisharp to true. Next, uninstall or disable C# Dev Kit. Finally, restart VS Code for this to take effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!